# How to prevent Bootstrap Navbar Toggle from pushing down content?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap with a static top navbar like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
   ...
  </div>
</nav>
```

In it's latest version 3.2.0, the Bootstrap navbar toggle unfortunately pushes down the content on small screens, when the menu is triggered.

How can this behaviour be prevented, i.e. keep the content static and let the mobile menu overlay the content like it used to be in previous versions?

Comment: add the `navbar-fixed` class to it when it reaches said small width?

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue and the navbar shouldn't be fixed at the top.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the best way to fix your issue but this is what I did to get my intended results (which is similar to what you've asked - to stop the navbar expansion from pushing down the divs below it).

First, find out at what width your menu collapses to your drop down menu list in your bootstrap file.

Using CSS, for my collapsed state, I did

```
#NavBar {
    position: absolute; -- this is what positioned my navbar at the top without pushing any content down (and also doesn't follow when you scroll down)
    width: 100%; -- you'll have to modify this to how big your width is
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

and for my normal state, I did

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    #NavBar {
        position: relative; -- normal navbar usage
    }
}
```

Hope this works for you as it did for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing different code for collapsed and normal state, we can write just single code as :

```
@media (max-width: 768px) { //bootstrap 3 collapses navbar at 768px
    #NavBar{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
}
```