# Prevent bootstrap navbar-inverse toggle pushing contents

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[Possible dublicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923117/how-to-prevent-bootstrap-navbar-toggle-from-pushing-down-content)

I want to prevent bootstrap navbar-inverse toggle pushing contents in mobile view.
I already tried several tricks like:

> $('.navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
> $('.navbar').addClass("navbar-fixed-top"); });
> $('.navbar-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
> $('.navbar').removeClass("navbar-fixed-top"); });

or

> $('.navbar-collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
> $('.navbar').css({'position':'absolute'}); });
> $('.navbar-collapse').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
> $('.navbar').css({'position':'relative'}); });

But all they do is either deforming the page or navbar itself. I don't want to use a fixed top navbar because of the page design. I am asking for any workaround suggestions?